# Set bar color via style role in googlevis package for R

Tags: r, googlevis

I'm using the [GoogleVis Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_intro.html) for R but I'm failing to use a column as [data role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles?hl=pt_br#stylerole) to change the style of the bar. Currently my dataframe looks like this:

[image]

All I wanted to do was to control the bar color via the "style" column. I have tried renaming it to *value.style* as well as *municipio.style* but none of these worked. When I create the graph using the `googleVis::gvisTimeline()` function it just ignores the colors in this column and proccess the graph with the default color schema.

The result I wanted to achieve is this:
[image]

However I'm currently getting this:
[image]

I know I can manually adjust this by using the "options" when processing the chart, but for hundred of reasons I would rather do it using the style role column, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the style column to the 'barlabel' parameter:

```
googleVis::gvisTimeline(data=cronograma_final,
                         rowlabel="municipio",
                         barlabel=c("value", "value.style"),
                         start="start", 
                         end="end",
                         options=list(timeline="{groupByRowLabel:true}"))
```

OBS.: I renamed it to 'value.style'